# I'm getting the wrong year on a date for coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

I'm trying to get the first and last day of the current quarter for the previous year. For some reason, the following code,

```
 <cfset LastYear = dateAdd('yyyy', -1, now()) > 
            <cfset FirstDayOfQuarterLastYear = CreateDate(LastYear, (quarter-1)*3 + 1, 1) > 
            <cfset LastDayOfQuarterLastYear = DateAdd("d", -1, DateAdd("m", 3, FirstDayOfQuarterLastYear)) > 
            LastYear: #LastYear#<br>
            FirstDayOfQuarterLastYear: #FirstDayOfQuarterLastYear#<br>
            LastDayOfQuarterLastYear: #LastDayOfQuarterLastYear#<br>
```

It gives me

```
LastYear: {ts '2016-01-13 11:05:06'}
FirstDayOfQuarterLastYear: {ts '42382-01-01 00:00:00'}
LastDayOfQuarterLastYear: {ts '42382-03-31 00:00:00'}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a date as the year parameter. You want to use the year only

```
<cfset FirstDayOfQuarterLastYear = CreateDate(year(LastYear), (quarter-1)*3 + 1, 1) >
```